# Boot Ubuntu from USB - bootorder

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I am a newbie so sorry if the question is very stupid.

I want to install Ubuntu20.04 on my laptop. I have created a bootable pendrive with ISO image using rufus.

I understand that I have to plug-in the USB and restart the PC, and then go to the BIOS menu and change the BIOS order and plce my USB first (in boot order).

1. In almost all videos I referred, I could see the name of the pendrive (Sandisk or XYZ USB) in the boot order. However, I do not see that option in my case. Which of these do I move to first pos? Current BootOrder:

[image: Screen picture]

2. Also, there are 2 UEFI Boot order and the Legacy boot order. Which one do I have to change?

I am using HP Notebook with Core i5 processor, and I want to install Ubuntu20.04

Comment: For better results DISABLE Legacy/CSM in the firmware settings. You want to boot and consequently install in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

1. USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk as first.
2. If you have the UEFI function turned on, you set it in UEFI but if not, in LEGACY.

You can also use the F9 boot menu key when starting your computer and select a device from the list.

Comment: It may not be the F9 key. See the computers documentation to find the correct key or keys to enter the BIOS for your computer.

Comment: #2 makes no sense at all. UEFI is a firmware (it replaced BIOS a DECADE ago), not a "function". UEFI mode is what you (and the OP) want, end of story. Do NOT use Legacy (the years is 2022, not 2011!). The correct suggestion is therefore to DISABLE Legacy/CSM so the installer boots and installs in UEFI mode as it should be.

Comment: @David The OP mentions a HP laptop so F9 is indeed applicable.